# How to time child processes in bash?

Tags: bash, time, child-process

I have a program that is a compiled binary that calls a whole bunch (~300) of child bash scripts. I would just like a way to time each of those child processes to find out which ones take the longest. The problem comes from the fact that I cannot change the compiled binary (by adding for example `time foo.sh >> bar_log.txt`). I can change the child scripts, so in theory I could move them to a different location and replace them with scripts that just call the ones from the new location with the `time` command, but again -- there are 300+ with unique names and whatnot. I was wondering if there was a way to call the original binary and get a log of the times to execute the child processes.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also have limited access to additional programs and cannot download/install new ones. For example, I do not have `atop.`

Comment: What resolution do you need? Is integer-second accuracy enough?

Comment: If need be, yes. I'd prefer ms resolution as some of these processes are quite quick. But I'm really only interested in the longest ones which take on the order of seconds/10s of seconds.

Comment: Also, what version of shell do you have? We've got more performant options with recent bash 4.x

Comment: (particularly, `printf %()T` is a much higher-performance alternative to running `date` as a subprocess).

Comment: In a real-world situation, btw, I'd find a way to make [Sysdig](https://www.sysdig.org/) available. Even if you can't install new software in a container running your code, Sysdig run on the host can trace content in containers -- and it's very, *very* thorough and low-overhead.

Comment: I have GNU bash version 4.1.2(1)

Comment: Do you have `strace`? If so, how about `strace -fT`

Comment: @bishop, ...`strace` is pretty darned heavyweight in terms of performance impact. Particularly in follow-forks mode, I wouldn't trust it not to modify the timings enough to make their value questionable.

Comment: Yeah, but the `strace` performance penalty is a function of the number of syscalls, @CharlesDuffy. We have no idea what the OP is wanting, other than processes lasting more than second(s), up to tens of seconds. Maybe this means they're stalling on I/O so the `strace` impact will be minor. If `strace` is too much, then there is also [`perf`](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html).

Comment: @bishop, right. And if those processes are currently slow somewhere other than individual user<->kernel switches, making syscalls much more expensive is going to have the effect of distorting measurements intended to determine where bottlenecks are at during a normal, uninstrumented run to shift time measured towards things doing lots of (potentially fast) syscalls rather than individual slow ones.

Comment: ...this is why I'm fond of sysdig -- it's not jumping back into userspace, just throwing a record onto a ring buffer for each syscall while staying in kernel land, so the overhead to trace every syscall is on the scale of a few percent.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the information. I just tried strace since, to a novice, it seemed like the simpler thing, however to no avail. It seems to time every syscall but I can't seem to find timing of the parents or parents of parents of those. Also, the log file is huge, taking several minutes just to grep for stuff. All I'm looking for is a log file with entires like `foo1.sh <0.08> // foo2.sh <5.01> // ...` I'll now try @CharlesDuffy's solution below (though to be honest I'm not entirely sure I understand it ;P )

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable `ENV` (for POSIX shells; for bash when not started under the name `sh`, `BASH_ENV`) is parsed *even by noninteractive shells* as the location of a script to run on startup.

Thus, you can create a file that initializes tracing:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  # SECONDS is time since the start of this individual script
  PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:$SECONDS+'
else
  # note that calling $(date) slows your code substantially
  # nothing to do about it without shell extensions, however.
  PS4=':${0}:$(date)+'
fi
set -x
```

...and set both `ENV` and `BASH_ENV` to point to that file.

Comment: may be useful to trap exit adding `trap ': exiting $?' EXIT` before `set -x`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Do I run this file before running my compiled binary? Where does the output go? What is the [-n $BASH_VERSION ] for? (My `$BASH_VERSION` output is `4.1.2(1)-release`)

Comment: @WarBro, no, you don't run it directly -- you create two environment variables, called `ENV` and `BASH_ENV`, each containing the name of the file with this code (as the answer already says). Contents of that files named by those variables (one or the other, depending on whether the shell is POSIX-y, as the answer already says) will then be executed during noninteractive shell startup. Output goes to stderr by default, though you could open a FD pointing somewhere else and set `BASH_XTRACEFD` to the number of that FD to direct it somewhere else if the active shell is bash.

Comment: @WarBro, `[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]` (spaces are important -- `[ -n` and `[-n` are different) checks if your shell is bash at all. Since you were talking about this being shells started by a compiled program you can't change, we don't have any reason to believe that that shell *is* bash at all, rather than being `/bin/sh`, so it's important to test both cases.

Comment: Ahhh, I misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I've just tried that but I encounter two issues: 1) Like strace, it seems to be giving the time on every command, which is not useless, but also missing part of what I need which is the elapsed time of each child process, which may be a tree like structure that goes all the way down to the syscalls, but I would like the times at each level of the tree as well. 2) The compiled binary is called from an interactive shell script, and the output of the set -x only seems to be the calls from that parent script, one of which is the compiled binary, but I see no other output from its children...

Comment: @WarBro, `$SECONDS` is time-since-startup for the current script. So you take the last `SECONDS` for each script, and that *is* your total time for that piece to run. And you can compare the `SECONDS` value from each line to the immediately prior line, and the difference gives you the runtime required. So you *do* have elapsed time (but for the very last command -- for that, consider adopting the `trap` suggestion in the very first comment), *and* individual command time.

Comment: As for there being untraced child processes, are you sure it's using a shell to call them at all? If there's no shell, then none of this takes place (and I'm not sure to what extent this remains a bash question).

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it properly. I have interactive shell script 1 startup.sh. Among things it does is warn if a results folder already exists, detects the OS, decompresses the appropriate binary (originally written in python), and calls that binary. The binary then runs and calls a whole bunch of bash scripts in a folder called OS_scripts (using the OS detected in the startup script). The only thing I see when I run ./startup.sh is the the call to the binary with the time `44+ ./pck-32 --checklist RedHat_6` and then `410+echo 'done'` with nothing in between.

Comment: If `pck-32` isn't a shell script, that's no surprise -- by its nature, logging bash commands only logs, well, bash commands. That said, that doesn't look like a PS4 value I provided -- are you *just* using `SECONDS` with no preceding source file and line number?. (*If* your `44` and `410` are `SECONDS` values, then you know that `pck-32` took 366 seconds... well, sorta -- the first character in `PS4` can be duplicated to show nesting depth, which is why it's good practice to use a sigil like `:`; if you're not using a sigil, your output gets harder to interpret).

Comment: If you're asserting that `pck-32` is running bash commands and *those* shells aren't logged, then we'd need to look into that. Maybe something in `pck-32` or elsewhere resets `ENV` (or the whole of your environment). There's various hackery available to work around that kind of thing, and various countermeasures to it -- if your software is deliberately written to not be dependent on the surrounding runtime environment, then we get into a cat-and-mouse game that's beyond the scope of a reasonable StackOverflow question.

Comment: (...and just to be sure: you *did* set both `ENV` and `BASH_ENV`, not just one, right? Because if those scripts start with `#!/bin/sh`, then `BASH_ENV` will do nothing. By contrast, if they start with `#!/usr/bin/env sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, then you get a whole new set of potential approaches based on PATH manipulation).

Comment: (of course, it's *possible* to override the binaries a specific process tree sees at `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` using a process-local filesystem namespace with some bind mounts added, and thus to run your program -- and only your program -- with a completely custom shell, but that's one of those things that's outside-reasonable-scope).

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you don't just unpack your binary yourself? Unpacking a self-extracting binary isn't exactly hard (details differ, but within UNIXlikes they're built with one of three or four common tools -- sharutils or one of its competitors), and then you can edit the scripts within to your heart's content.

Comment: `pck-32` is not a shell script, but it calls all the scripts in the OS_scripts folder, which are shell scripts. I don't know what it does to the environment, but I do know it interacts with environment variables (the scripts in OS_scripts set environment variables that the binary captures). Yes, I set both ENV and BASH_ENV. Also, yes it includes the source name and the line number, I just left them out in my comment for simplicity. There are reasons I can't edit the script (it's complicated).

Comment: *nod*. If it clears environment variables it doesn't recognize, then the `ENV`/`BASH_ENV` variables may not be making it through to the shells the executable calls. See discussion above of alternate approaches (such as hooking in an interpreter of your choice that reasserts those variables before calling through to the real shell).